# query to get balance for a ledger report page

Tags: php, mysql, report

i want to build a ledger report page

this is my table structure for that..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tran` (
  `tran_no` int(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'S.S.N.',
  `date` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `amt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `tran` (`tran_no`, `date`, `cid`, `ref`, `amt`, `type`) VALUES
(1, '2014/04/25', 1, '123', '35280', 'Sales'),
(2, '2014/04/25', 1, '124', '35280', 'Sales'),
(3, '2014/04/01', 3, '1236', '2000', 'Sales'),
(4, '2014/04/25', 1, '126', '35280', 'Sales'),
(5, '2014/04/25', 1, '127', '35280', 'Sales'),
(6, '2014/04/24', 1, '128', '50000', 'Sales'),
(7, '2014/04/24', 1, '131', '50000', 'Sales'),
(8, '2014/04/24', 1, '129', '12000', 'Sales'),
(9, '2014/04/24', 1, '130', '11000', 'Sales'),
(10, '2014/04/22', 2, '156', '50000', 'Sales'),
(12, '2014/04/23', 1, '130', '54321', 'Sales'),
(13, '2014/04/24', 2, '131', '54320', 'Sales'),
(14, '2014/04/27', 2, '132', '12345', 'Sales'),
(15, '2014/04/27', 2, '133', '55555', 'Sales'),
(16, '2014/04/08', 2, '1234', '30000', 'Receipt'),
(17, '2014/04/11', 2, '1235', '5000',  'Receipt'),
(18, '2014/04/01', 2, '1236', '2000', 'Receipt'),
(19, '2014/04/14', 2, '1237', '5000', 'Receipt'),
(20, '2014/04/20', 2, '134', '50000', 'Receipt'),
(21, '2014/04/28', 2, '111', '45455', 'Receipt'),
(22, '2014/04/28', 2, '112', '54545', 'Receipt'),
(23, '2014/05/01', 3, '1234', '55000', 'Sales'),
(24, '2014/05/02', 3, '113', '25000', 'Receipt');
```

there is one other table for customer information with opening balance

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `cid` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Customer ID',
  `cname` char(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Name',
  `cadd` char(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Address',
  `cemail` char(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `cphone` char(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Phone',
  `cperson` char(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contact Person',
  `cmob` char(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mobile Number',
  `cob` int(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Opening Balance',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `cname` (`cname`,`cadd`,`cemail`,`cphone`,`cperson`,`cob`),
  KEY `cperson` (`cperson`),
  KEY `cmob` (`cmob`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customer`
--

INSERT INTO `customer` (`cid`, `cname`, `cadd`, `cemail`, `cphone`, `cperson`, `cmob`, `cob`) VALUES
(1, 'CASH', 'N/A', '', 'n/a', 'CASH', '', 0),
(2, 'GURUDEV ENGINEERING', 'DHARMA CHOWK', '', '056527784', 'RAJAN KANDEL', '9845045093', 50000),
(3, 'ASIAN GENERAL', 'DHARMA CHOWK', 'n/a', '056530757', 'PADAM CHHETRI', '9845082712', 100000),
(4, 'KANDEL ELECTRIC', 'DHARMA CHOWK', 'n/a', '056526105', 'BHOJRAJ KANDEL', '9845077618', 55555);
```

for ledger report page of CID-2, i wish this to be displayed as--

```
REPORT of CID-2
-------------------------------------------------
|   date    | ref   | sales | receipt | balance |
|-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|opening bal        |       |         | 50000   |
|2014/04/01 | 1236  |       | 2000    | 48000   |
|2014/04/08 | 1234  |       | 30000   | 18000   |
|2014/04/11 | 1235  |       | 5000    | 13000   |
|2014/04/14 | 1237  |       | 5000    | 8000    |
|2014/04/20 | 134   |       | 50000   | -42000  |
|2014/04/22 | 156   | 50000 |         | 8000    |
|2014/04/24 | 131   | 54320 |         | 62320   |
|2014/04/27 | 133   | 55555 |         | 117875  |
|2014/04/27 | 132   | 12345 |         | 130220  |
|2014/04/28 | 111   |       | 45455   | 84765   |
|2014/04/28 | 112   |       | 54545   | 30220   |
|-----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|closing balance    | 172220| 192000  | 30220   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

i retrieved all columns and first and last row from different queries but couldn't get the balance column. i tried different queries from different suggestions from other questions & answers from STACKEXCHANGE, but none of them gave my desired result..

please help me solving this....

thanks in advance....

EDITTED: WHAT I'VE TRIED IS--

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT sum(samt), sum(ramt) FROM tran WHERE cid='$cid'") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connect));
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4);
$TotalSales = $row4['sum(samt)'];
$TotalReceipt = $row4['sum(ramt)'];
$balance = $ob + $TotalSales - $TotalReceipt;

echo "
<table border='1' cellpadding='6' style='font-size:14px' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr bgcolor='#006699' align='center' style='font-weight:bold;'>
        <td width='150px'>Date</td>
        <td>Sales No.</td>";
        if ($rs->cname!='CASH') { echo "<td width='150px'>Receipt No.</td>"; }
echo"
        <td width='200px'>Sales</td>";
        if ($rs->cname!='CASH') { echo "<td width='150px'>Receipt</td>"; }
echo"
    </tr>";
// select tran
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tran WHERE cid = '$cid' ORDER BY date";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($connect));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "
    <tr bgcolor='#999911' align='center'>
        <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
        <td>";
        if ($row['sref'] > 0) {
        echo "<a href='salesedit.php?ssn=$row[ssn]' class=slink>" . $row['sref'];
        } else {
            echo " ";
        }
        echo "
        </td>";
        if ($rs->cname!='CASH') {
            echo "<td>";
            if ($row['rref'] > 0) {
                echo "<a href='receiptedit.php?rsn=$row[rsn]' class='slink'>" . $row['rref'] . "</a>";
            } else {
                echo " ";
            }
        }
        echo "</td>";
        if ($row['samt'] > 0) {
        echo "<td align='right'>Rs." . number_format(($row['samt']), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td align='center'>-</td>";
        }
        if ($rs->cname!='CASH') {
            if ($row['ramt'] > 0) {
                echo "<td align='right'>Rs." . number_format(($row['ramt']), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td align='center'>-</td>";
            }
        }
        echo
        "</td>
    </tr>";
    }
echo "
    <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' align='center'>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>" . $n . " Sale(s)</td>";
                if ($rs->cname!='CASH') { echo "<td>" . $n1 . " Receipt(s)</td>"; }
echo"
        <td align='right'>Rs. " . number_format(($TotalSales), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>";
        if ($rs->cname!='CASH') { echo "<td align='right'>Rs. " . number_format(($TotalReceipt), 2, '.', ',') . "</td>"; }
echo "
    </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried.  Also, SQL Fiddle is a great way to present a problem with real data and table structures.

Comment: Why is date VARCHAR? (Hint: IT SHOULDN'T BE) Likewise for ref and amt

Comment: what i've tried could be something rubbish, coz i'm a very beginner on php & mysql. and i found at sqlfiddle it couldn't be performed. so shall i post it editing my question?

Comment: Your sample ledger page report starts with a nonzero opening balance. Where did you get that value? Have you concluded yet that you have enough types of data in your tables to generate this report?

Comment: the opening balance is retrieved from 'customer' table. and whatever i've done doesn't have any error. i'm just not being able to get 'balance' column and my question is regarding that only....